# Abelian group and commutativity problem

Tags: abelian-groups

Let us assume that we have a group G with the following property :
for every 5 discrete elements of G , at least 2 of them can be commutated.

Is G an abelian group?

Comment: "can be commutated" means that a.b=b.a

Comment: No, there are easy example of nonabelian groups with this property (though for obvious reasons, only quite small ones).

Comment: Could you please provide an example of a nonabelian group with this property?

Comment: I think it would be better if you just sat down and actually tried to come up with one (just try the nonabelian groups you know one by one, you should fairly quickly see an example).

Comment: Actually ,it took me hours to solve the same problem with 4 elements instead of 5. My experiance with abelian groups is limited unfortunatelly...

Comment: You only need to actually start looking at examples.

Comment: For $3$ elements it is true, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980392/if-at-least-one-pair-of-the-elements-a-b-c-in-g-commute-then-g-is-abelian).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think it should hold for $4$ as well, and for any fixed number, it will hold as long as the group is sufficiently large.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I didn't actually check if $Q_8$ worked, as a smaller example did the trick (for this specific number).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sure, the two $3$-cycles commute.

Answer (score 0):

Up to dimension $12$ there are $8$ non-abelian groups, namely $$S_3,D_4,Q_8,D_5,C_3\rtimes C_4, C_2\times S_3, A_4,D_6.
$$ Their Cayley tables are available, so we can easily check whether or not for each $5$ distinct elements, there are two which commute. Certainly this is true for $S_3$ and $Q_8$, since for $S_3$, choosing $5$ elements means choosing all but one element. If the identity is among the $5$ elements, it commutes with everything and we are done, if not, then the two $3$-cycles commute. For $Q_8=\{\pm 1,\pm i,\pm j,\pm k\}$, choosing $5$ elements means, that we have $a$ and $-a$ among them, which do commute. I leave it to you to check the other groups.

So the answer is: no, the group need not be abelian in general. However, it is true if the order of $G$ is big enough.